# Сохранение форматирования текста при копировании из Word в браузер

Tags: javascript, ms-word, форматирование, textarea

Есть проблема следующего характера. Надо сделать так, чтобы при копировании текста из MS Word (хотя бы пока только из него) и последующей вставки этого текста в браузер (например, в textarea), сохранялись некоторые атрибуты форматирования (начертание, цвет, размер). И вставлялись в код в виде тегов, очевидно. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать. Есть ли какие-нибудь готовые решения?

Если просматривать то, что попадает в буфер обмена при копировании текста из Word, то там есть довольно много информации. Смотрел через программу CLCL. И теоретически, нужные сведения можно, наверное, выдернуть оттуда с помощью JS. По крайней мере, шрифт, размер и цвет я там нашел. Но выглядит этот вариант довольно трудоемким и не универсальным. Может есть какие-то другие возможности?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable).

Comment: Да, действительно. Div с атрибутом contenteditable разом решил все проблемы. Как все оказалось просто. Спасибо Вам большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nazarpunk в комментариях дал верный ответ,

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

полностью решает задачу.